# Inter-Processor Communications, one processor writes, the other reads

Tags: python, sockets, process, ipc

I use ZeroMQ for IPC. It works perfect when one process listens a socket (pipe or unix socket?), and the other writes.

The app that listens:

```
...
listener = IPCListener()
listener.startup_thread = Thread(target=listener.serve)
listener.startup_thread.daemon = True
listener.startup_thread.start()

class IPCListener()

    def __init__(self)
        self.context = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.sock = self.context.socket(znq.REP)
        self.sock.connection('ipc:///tmp/myapp')

    def serve(self):
        while True:
            message = self.sock.recv()
            response = self.handle_message(message)
            self.sock.send(response)

    def handle_message(self, message):
        if message == 'foo':
            do_something_useful()
```

here's the manager:

```
context = zmq.Context.instance()
sock = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
sock.bind('ipc:///tmp/myapp')
sock.send('foo')
response = sock.recv()
print response
```

The thing is I need to run several workers(processes) of my app. It goes without saying I get `'sock.error: [Error 98] Already in use'`

I don't know if there's a way I can make several processes read one common socket? May be it's not possible with zmq, but what can handle this?

Comment: Are all processes using the same connection 'ipc:///tmp/myapp'?  That looks like the problem.  That file might actually be created/locked.  Consider making the file 'ipc://tmp/myapp-%d" % os.getpid() or something that varies from process to process so you're not reusing the same file.

Comment: this makes sense, but I though there's another, simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to handling this is to just have your main process/thread listen on the socket, and then once it gets a message, hand the processing off to one of the worker processes.

Comment: hmm, i think it's not possible. I run bunch of workers with uWSGI.